# Implementing a drop down menu that accesses movies with the same titles. React,Axios,MovieDB API

Tags: css, reactjs, api

I am making a movie search app and right now I can search for a movie and the backdrop, poster image, title, and popularity will apear on screen. I ran into an issue where I have no way of accessing different movies with the same name. For example when I search "Joker" it reveals the first title that comes up as you will notice in my code

```
const title = res.data['results'][0]['title'];
```

The '[0]' is significant because it is only accessing the first movie in the search, here is an image of the browser search of the API for reference:
[image]

Now there is also going to be a different number of movietitles with the same name depending on the search and each one is listed as a different number under the API. The most recent and popular being `[0]`, and then `[1]`, etc. I figure I need a for loop or forEach to collect the results[*number*] and then return all of the ['original_title'] or ['title'] and then return each result as a drop-down menu on search rather than on submit so users can click on them as they are searching for them to auto complete. This is also my first project with React and I am not sure if I should make this inside of the `clickHandler` or where else to put it.

Mostly all of my code is in Movielist.js but here is all 3 of my code files just in case. I am not tied to my idea of fixing it, just whatever is the easiest way to implement searching for a movie with the same title.

Movielist.js

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../CSS/style.css'

export default class Movielist extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
    popularity: "",
    poster: "",
    background: "",
  }

    clickHandler = (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
           const query = event.target.value;
           const API_KEY = 'caf02a958f137f43327649b2b8721302';
    axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${query}`)
      .then(res => {

        const title = res.data['results'][0]['title'];
        this.setState({ title });

        const popularity = res.data['results'][0]['popularity']
        this.setState({ popularity });

        const poster = res.data['results'][0]['poster_path']
        this.setState({ poster });

        const background = res.data['results'][0]['backdrop_path']
        this.setState({ background })


      })
        }
    }

  render() {
    const backgroundStyle = {
      backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), 
  url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${this.state.background})`,

      backgroundSize: "cover",
      height: "100vh"
  }

    return (
      <div id="main-div" style={backgroundStyle}>
        <div id="second-div">
         <input type="search" id="search" onKeyDown={event => this.clickHandler(event)} />
         <h1 id="title">Title: {this.state.title}</h1>
         <h1 id="popularity">Popularity: {this.state.popularity}</h1>
         <img id="poster" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300${this.state.poster}`} />
      </div>
    </div>

    )
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import React from "react"
import Movielist from './components/Movielist'



function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Movielist />
        </div>

    )
}

export default App
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of stuff you can do, lots of ways, for example this:

Inside `clickHandler` set whole results array to state:

`this.setState({ results: res.data.results })`

then inside render use `.map` function to iterate over results and for each result item render (return) something

```
<div id="main-div" style={backgroundStyle}>
<input type="search" id="search" onKeyDown={event => this.clickHandler(event)} />
  <div id="results">
    {this.state.results.map(item => {
      return (
        <div key={item.id}>
           <h1 id="title">Title: {item.title}</h1>
           <h1 id="popularity">Popularity: {item.popularity}</h1>
           Basically render whatever you want
        </div>
      )
    })}
  <div>
</div>
```

You can limit how many items you want to show by using `.slice` function like that `this.state.results.slice(0, 5).map(...` (will slice first 5 items). You can use it inside render or even when you use `setState`

Comment: where in render do I put that?

Comment: Wherever you want to render :)


Just added some clarification, hope it makes sense now